# Extract column of strings from dataframe in R when they are "factors"

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Currently, I have a large dataframe in which I don't necessarily know the names of all the rows, which are stored as strings in the first column (in this case, names of countries for which some data is supplied). I need to get that data out to do other things, and I just happen to know the first 56 rows have all of the names I need precisely once each.

I thought I could just make a vector of these names iterating through with a for loop like so:

```
dat=read.csv("foo.csv",header=TRUE)
Names=character(56)
for (i in 1:56){Names[i]=dat[[i,1]]}
```

but what happens is that I end up with a bunch of integers in Names. When I run `str(dat$NAMES)` [the column in which I am interested], I get the following:

```
Factor with 56 levels "Angola", "Benin",...: 1 3 4 5 15 27 32 33 39 40 ...
```

These appear to be the integers I'm getting, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the strings instead.

Comment: Try `Names <- as.character(dat[1:56, 1])`. Or set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.csv`.

Comment: stringsAsFactors=FALSE worked like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: Perfect. Then simply do `Names <- dat[1:56, 1]`, no need for a loop. Or `Names <- unique(dat[, 1])` to be sure there are not more (or less) than 56 countries.

Comment: @markus, you're absolutely correct about using `read.csv( ,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` to avoid the factors in the first place. And also correct for your suggested use of  `as.character()` for situations where you have Factors in an existing data.frame.  Why not post as an answer in a form @PeaceBlaster can copy/paste/run and then he can accept it as the answer?

Comment: Note also that it is not right to use the double `[[` like you do in `dat[[i,1]]`. Just `dat[i, 1]` is the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the first place was that `read.csv` produced a factor in the first column when OP thought it was a character vector.

We can avoid this while loading the data into R setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.csv`.

```
dat <- read.csv("foo.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#extract the first 56 entries from the first column
Names <- dat[1:56, 1]
```

If `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is not an option, then use `as.character` to convert that vector to be of type character.

```
dat <- read.csv("foo.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
#extract the first 56 entries from the first column
Names <- as.character(dat[1:56, 1])
```